# Multinomial Logistic Regression as Measure of Association

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, multinomial-logit

I have a dataset with say about 50 variables related to lifestyle risk factors, and I want to measure the association between these lifestyle predictors (e.g. smoking, alcohol consumption, physical activity etc) and a dependent variable, say *high cholesterol* (three levels: Normal; Borderline High; High) using **multinomial logistic regression**.

My questions are:

1. Should I run the model for each variable separately and interpret the result (significance of association, relative risk ratios etc), or it is better to use all (or at least a group of) the variables?
2. If likelihood ratio chi-square test shows that the model *does not* fit significantly better than an empty model, how does it affect the interpretation of the result?